# Apache .htaccess rule to rewrite subfolder to query param not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my web root folder, I have an `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^assessments_tools/(.+)" "assessments_tools/index.php?file=$1" [R,L]
```

This means that `/assessments_tools/myers-briggs/` should rewrite to `/assessments_tools/index.php?file=myers-briggs`. However, I cannot get this to work; it always returns a 404.

On the server, `/assessessments_tools/` actually exists as a directory. If I use the same rule for a non-existent directory, e.g. `RewriteRule "^foo/(.+)" "assessments_tools/index.php?file=$1" [R,L]`, it works. So, my guess is that it *may* have something to do with the fact that `/assessments_tools/` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling MultiViews fixed it.

```
Options -MultiViews
```